# Custom Event & Command Loader Script used to work and now spits errors? [NodeJS/DiscordJS]

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

I'm currently in the process of making a Discord Bot (v13) and trying to use my old custom Event/Command Loading script, that used to work on v12.5.1, now I'm having error after error.

The error I'm receiving is : `[Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'C:\Users\EvilGaming\Desktop\EvilBot\commands\Help.js'] { errno: -4052, code: 'ENOTDIR', syscall: 'scandir', path: 'C:\\Users\\EvilGaming\\Desktop\\EvilBot\\commands\\Help.js' }`

the file exists:

```yaml
    Directory: C:\Users\EvilGaming\Desktop\EvilBot\commands


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        30/09/2021     17:43           4089 Help.js
```

```js
const {
    readdir,
    readdirSync
} = require("fs");

const categories = readdirSync(`${__dirname}/../../commands`);

            try {
                categories.forEach(async(category) => {
                    readdir(`${__dirname}/../../commands/${category}/`, (err) => {
                        if (err) return console.error("ERROR HERE\n" + err);
                        const init = async() => {
                            const commands = readdirSync(`${__dirname}/../../commands/${category}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
                            for (const file of commands) {
                                const cmd = require(`${__dirname}/../../commands/${category}/${file}`);
                                const command = new cmd(this);
                                this.commands.set(command.name.toLowerCase(), command);
                                console.warn("Command Loader", `Loaded ${cmd.name} from ${category}.`);
                                if (command.aliases && Array.isArray(command.aliases)) {
                                    for (let i = 0; i < command.aliases.length; i++) {
                                        this.aliases.set(command.aliases[i], command);
                                    }
                                    console.warn("Command Loader", `${cmd.name} from ${category} with aliases ${command.aliases} loaded.`);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        init();
                    });
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('CLIENT', error);
            }
```

The Tree Directory is like so:

```yaml
C:.
├───commands
├───events
├───settings
└───src
    ├───client
    └───structures
```

Comment: Does `C:\Users\EvilGaming\Desktop\EvilBot\commands\Help.js` actually exist?

Comment: Yes, it actually exists but it's somehow reading it as a directory and not as a file in said directory, the directory is `commands` and `Help.js` is the javascript command file. @MrMythical

Comment: maybe try renaming the file `help` in lowercase and every `Help` into `help`, lowercasing sometimes fixed my problems and I always do that in every file I have concerning programming